# Calling JSON and data retrieval working in browser but not in Cordova emulator or mobile

Tags: ajax, json, wcf

I am building a mobile web app using html5, there I am fetching the data from my WCF rest serice. Problem is it's working fine in browser, when converted in to app using Apache Cordova it's not working.

I'm getting `http_request.readyState :4` and `http_request.status :0` instead of 200. I thought it's a problem with cross domain issue so used ajax instead of Java function and enabled **CORS** in `web.config` of WCF still problem persists

Can anyone help out please?

Thanks in advance

Vikram

PS : when using ajax function its getting into error function but displaying a error message success:200, don't what it means

```
$.ajax({
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://dev_test_srv/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/123?callback=?",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(123);
                    alert("working");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error.statusText + "-" + error.status);
                }
});

var data_file = "http://dev_test_srv/RestServiceImpl.svc/Employees/" + id + "/" + pwd;
alert(data_file);

var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

try {
                // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
                http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {
                // Internet Explorer Browsers
                try {
                    http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
                    try {
                        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        // Something went wrong
                        alert("Your browser broke!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
}

http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                alert(http_request.readyState + '--' + http_request.status);
                if (http_request.readyState == 4 && http_request.status == 200) {
                    var stringouptut = http_request.responseText;
                    var replacedstring = stringouptut.replace(/\\/g, "");
                    var newresult = "{ \"Data\": " + replacedstring.substring(replacedstring.indexOf("["));
                    var final = newresult.substring(0, newresult.length - 2) + " " + " }";

                    final = JSON.parse(final);

                    if (final.Data.length > 0) {

                        if (final.Data[0].status == "Valid") {

                            localStorage.UserId = id;

                            window.location = "doctors.html";
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById("lblerror").innerHTML = "Invalid Employee ID/Password";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
            http_request.send();
```

Config settings in `web.config` :

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders> 
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept"/>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />                             <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
    </customHeaders> 
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: thank u marc_s ,I did the changes